# How to find out changelog in between 5.4.0-1091-azure and 5.4.0-1094-azure kernels?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

My Ubuntu has performed an unattended upgrade from 5.4.0-1091-azure to 5.4.0-1094-azure kernels. I suspect this might had an effect on the performance of my Java application and I'd like to find a detailed list of changes in between the two versions. I have found a changelog for [5.4.0](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.4) but this is in the past. Can someone help me what's the best way to get a brief overview of the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the changelog [on the `linux-azure-5.4` source package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure-5.4); specifically, [this is the changelog for 1094](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure-5.4/5.4.0-1094.100%7E18.04.1):

> ```
> * CVE-2022-2602
>   - SAUCE: io_uring/af_unix: defer registered files gc to io_uring release
>   - SAUCE: io_uring/af_unix: fix memleak during unix GC
> * CVE-2022-41674
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211: fix u8 overflow in
>     cfg80211_update_notlisted_nontrans()
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211/mac80211: reject bad MBSSID elements
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211: ensure length byte is present before access
>   - SAUCE: wifi: mac80211_hwsim: avoid mac80211 warning on bad rate
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211: update hidden BSSes to avoid WARN_ON
> * CVE-2022-42721
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211: avoid nontransmitted BSS list corruption
> * CVE-2022-42720
>   - SAUCE: wifi: cfg80211: fix BSS refcounting bugs
> ```